# Creating A Custom Function That Can Handle Both Data Frames And Data Tables

Tags: r, function, dataframe, data.table

There may be a simple solution to this that I am missing, but I am not sure where to find this answer if it exists. I'm starting to work with the `data.table` class, but also want to be able to write functions that are compatible with, and return, `data.frame` objects and `data.table` objects.

Now, I'm aware that data.table uses the `UseMethod` function to set the argument of a function to data.frame if the function is meant to work with data.frames. I guess my question is, how to I designate this and have this kind of flexibility in a custom function?

Here's an example using the `arrange` function:

```
> require(plyr)
> 
> df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
> df <- arrange(df, a)
> class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
> 
> dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
> dt <- arrange(dt, a)
> class(dt)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

The class of the dataset was preserved in each call of `arrange`. Using `UseMethod`, I'm able to call `UseMethod("as.data.frame")` on the first argument of a custom function and it does convert it, however, I'm unsure as to what the method would be for setting the same object to convert back to its original class upon returning.

I can do this manually with if statements, i.e:

```
if (class(data)[1] == "data.table")) { data <- as.data.table(data) } else { data <- as.data.frame(data) }
```

But this feels too hard coded and I have the feeling there is a more advance way that I am missing.

Essentially, I want to create a custom function, that accepts either a data.frame or data.table object, converts that object to data.frame, does the data.frame based operation, and returns that object in whatever class it was originally in.

This could be a dumb question, but any insight would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Adding a merge example because `arrange` was a poorly chosen example:

```
> require(data.table)
> 
> dt1 <- data.table(a = 1:5)
> class(dt1)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> dt2 <- data.table(b = 1:5)
> class(dt2)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> 
> m <- merge.data.frame(dt1, dt2)
> class(m)
[1] "data.frame"
```

How does `merge.data.frame` know to convert the data.table objects to data.frame? Why doesn't this throw an error?

Comment: How about just `if(is.data.table(data)) { do data.table stuff } else { do data.frame stuff }`

Comment: That could certainly work, but I'd like to avoid having two methods in the same function if possible. I'm fine with taking the performance hit with data.frames. Ultimately, I think I'm wondering at how `arrange`, for example, can do as in my post. Does it actually have a method for data.table? I was watching a video on data.table and it was said that data.tables are converted to data.frames for functions that have no method for data.table. I'm trying to see if I can somehow designate that for my custom functions.

Comment: You can see how the `dplyr` methods are written by calling `dplyr:::arrange_.data.table` and the same for data.frame

Comment: Nice catch. I added an example of `merge.data.frame` at the bottom, which I think illustrates the behavior I want to emulate.

Comment: If you don't want two methods in the same function, write them in different functions and allow dispatching: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html Normal users (like me) really don't need this though; seems like the sort of thing one might need for package development, I suppose. Or, just write it only for data.table and do `setDT` at the front and `setDF` at the end.

Comment: You load `plyr` in your question which doesn't have a data.table method for arrange. I'd strongly recommend using `dplyr`, which does have a data table method as Richard Scriven pointed out.

Comment: @Frank Yeah, I think I'm just going to do the setDT, setDF with if statements as I originally considered. Thank you for the suggestion. And @Gregor, `arrange` in this case was just for the sake of the example, not a question concerning `arrange` in particular.